# Applying the font color & background color from a cell to a shape

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the following code to build a shape on one sheet based on the contents of a cell in another sheet. Unfortunately, the shape does not maintain the font color and background color of the original cell. I could write code to state the color and background, but given the macro that I am creating, this would be a lot of work. Does anyone have any ideas for how I can write code to capture the original color and background. I would greatly appreciate your help. Thank you!

```
    If ws1.Range("N3") <> 0 Then
Set b1 = ws2.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 525, 235, 70, 70)

    With b1

    .TextFrame.Characters.Text = ws1.Range("N3")
    .TextFrame.HorizontalAlignment = xlHAlignCenterAcrossSelection
    .TextFrame.VerticalAlignment = xlVAlignCenter
    .TextFrame.Characters.Font.FontStyle = "Segoe UI Symbol"
    .TextFrame.Characters.Font.Size = 40
    .TextFrame.Characters.Font.Bold = True
    .BackgroundStyle = msoBackgroundStyleNotAPreset
    .ShapeStyle = msoLineStylePreset1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to work:

```
Sub luxation()
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet, b1 As Shape, r As Range
    Set ws2 = ActiveSheet
    Set r = ws2.Range("N3")
    If r.Value <> 0 Then
        Set b1 = ws2.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 525, 235, 70, 70)
        With b1
            .TextFrame.Characters.Text = r.Value
            .TextFrame.HorizontalAlignment = xlHAlignCenterAcrossSelection
            .TextFrame.VerticalAlignment = xlVAlignCenter
            .TextFrame.Characters.Font.FontStyle = "Segoe UI Symbol"
            .TextFrame.Characters.Font.Size = 40
            .TextFrame.Characters.Font.Bold = True
            .TextFrame.Characters.Font.Color = r.Font.Color
            .ShapeStyle = msoLineStylePreset1
        End With
        b1.Select
        Selection.Interior.Color = r.Interior.Color
    End If
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Great solution! I would just change one thing.  Move setting the color to inside the "With b1"  clause with this line: .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = r.Interior.Color.  Just a bit cleaner...

Comment: @JohnnyD  Thank you for the comments!  **I will absolutely use your method in the future.**.  In the past, I used *Selection* because it has an *Interior.Color* and a *Shape* does not......................thanks again!

Comment: @Gary's Student... Certainly, as JohnnyD says, the solution is a great one. Thank you again! However, I did notice one thing. This solution relies on the cell, to which I am pointing, will be formatted. In other words, If I try to conditionally format "N3" (from the example above), although the conditional formatting may make N3 blue, b1 comes across as black. Do you know why this is happening? Is there a way around it? I was trying to use Excel's conditional formatting to avoid writing conditional statements into my code. Would make the code very long since there are 5 possibilities. Thanks!